# Android - Applying Code to Tabs (Layouts) in SlidingTabLayouts

Tags: android, material-design

I am an aspiring android developer with not a lot of experience and who is quite new to the field. As of late, I have been interested in implementing material design features in my first (to-be-published) app, specifically the SlidingTabLayout.

Because I am trying to support versions of android back to API 15, I have used the android support library and this [link](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) to build this SlidingTabLayout. However, I am not able to figure out how to apply any sort of java code to the specific layout `tab_1.xml` and `tab_2.xml` so that I can apply onClickListeners to buttons, initialize TextViews, etc... that exist within those layouts.

As far as I have tested, this cannot be done in the MainActivity because the setContentView is the MainActivity itself and not the tab layouts, but I may be wrong. Once again I am quite new to Android development, but any help is appreciated!

PS: I can add any kind of specific code if any clarification is needed as to what I am asking.

Comment: Just to stress, the link is pretty much essential to understanding the question, so please take a look at it!

Comment: It will have a viewpager and pager will show different fragments where content of tabs can be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to access the different kinds of views within the layout of the tabs. I don't have reputation to comment on your question. If possible please add your code above.  From the link you gave I see this code

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2,container,false);
    return v;
}
```

}

So to access views in the tab_2, you need to access them like this. For example you have a Button in tab_2 with id btn_1. Then

```
Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
```

If I am wrong let me know. I'll help you out. If you find this answer helpful, upvote my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not quite clear on where I use this example. Do I use the `v.findViewById` in my MainActivity `onCreate` or in my Tab2 java file? Currently I'm typing in the `v.findViewById` in my MainActivity file and the `v` is showing up red (some kind of error).

Comment: you have to use it in the onCreateView method of Tab2

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to use android view pager for more you can use this helper library https://raw.github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs/